# Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection Problem

Tags: symfony, symfony-routing

I am include an App.php (rounting) page but my front.php do not get the type RouteCollection object (`Argument #1 ($routes) must be of type Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection`)

I am doing the excercise on the page:
https://symfony.com/doc/6.2/create_framework/routing.html

My front.php must get from the App.php (routing and routingcollection) the object of type RouteCollection
`Argument #1 ($routes) must be of type Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection`

Comment: Please update your question to include the code and directory structure *you* used. If you're following the tutorial, file-names and paths are case sensitive on Unix like systems but are not on Windows unless you've installed and are using WSL.

Comment: Does your app.php file have the line `Use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;`?